# Set Material UI table default sorting

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, material-table

This should be much easier than what I'm seeing and I'm sure there is a better way. How can I set the default sorting of a Material UI table like the one below. I don't want a button at the top so the sorting can be changed, I want the table to sort, by protein, by default when the table is loaded.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowUp';

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, price) {
  return {
    name,
    calories,
    fat,
    carbs,
    protein,
    price,
    history: [
      {
        date: '2020-01-05',
        customerId: '11091700',
        amount: 3,
      },
      {
        date: '2020-01-02',
        customerId: 'Anonymous',
        amount: 1,
      },
    ],
  };
}

function Row(props) {
  const { row } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableRow sx={{ '& > *': { borderBottom: 'unset' } }}>
        <TableCell>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="expand row"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {row.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                History
              </Typography>
              <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">Total price ($)</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                    <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {historyRow.date}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{historyRow.customerId}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.amount}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {Math.round(historyRow.amount * row.price * 100) / 100}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </Box>
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Row.propTypes = {
  row: PropTypes.shape({
    calories: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    carbs: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    fat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        customerId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      }),
    ).isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    protein: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 3.99),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3, 4.99),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0, 3.79),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3, 2.5),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9, 1.5),
];

export default function CollapsibleTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Note this is not a DataGrid, this is a Material UI Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call sort on the row data before rendering it

```js
<TableBody>
  {rows
    .sort((a, b) => a.protein < b.protein ? -1 : 1)
    .map((row) => (
    <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
  ))}
</TableBody>
```